# 'List' object has no attribute 'startswith' - difficulty solving

Tags: python, django

Upon reviewing existing cases regarding this topic I have yet to find a solution.

I am trying to run my python server and keep running into this traceback:

```
    G:\inetpub\FaulknerandSonsLTD2\Website\Website>manage.py runserver
    Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\threading.py", line 926, in
_bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
        raise _exception[1]
      File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
        autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
      File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
      File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
        module = import_module(entry)
      File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 118, in import_module
        if name.startswith('.'):
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I have tried searching for the phrase 'startswith' in the entire project.

Are there any obvious suggestions as to where to find the root of the problem? Normally the traceback gives vital clues as to file locations.

Application Settings:

```
"""
Django settings for Website project.

Based on 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import posixpath
import pyodbc 


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '230f1c1d-ccaf-4db6-8d0c-afda7968d275'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Accounts.Account'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

LOGIN_URL = '/Website/login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', # existing backend
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'

# Application references
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "app",
    "Website",
    "Users.django_registration",
    "Users.current_user",
    "computedfields",
    # Accounting Applications Here
    "Accounting",
    # Education Applications Here
    "Education",
    "Education.Examinations",
    "Education.Grades",
    "Education.Homework",
    "Education.Lessons",
    "Education.Modules",
    "Education.Qualifications",
    "Education.Subjects",
    "Education.Subjects.ComputerScience",
    "Education.Subjects.English",
    "Education.Subjects.Geography",
    "Education.Subjects.History",
    "Education.Subjects.Mathematics",
    "Education.Subjects.Music",
    "Education.Subjects.PSHE",
    "Education.Subjects.ReligiousStudies",
    "Education.Subjects.Science",
    # Healthcare Applications Here
    "Healthcare",
    "Healthcare.Asthma",
    "Healthcare.AtrialFibrillation",
    "Healthcare.BloodPressure",
    "Healthcare.Cancer",
    "Healthcare.CervicalScreening",
    "Healthcare.ChronicHeartDisease",
    "Healthcare.ChronicKidneyDisease",
    "Healthcare.COPD",
    "Healthcare.CVD",
    "Healthcare.Dementia",
    "Healthcare.Depression",
    "Healthcare.Diabetes",
    "Healthcare.Epilepsy",
    "Healthcare.HeartFailure",
    "Healthcare.Hypertension",
    "Healthcare.LearningDisability",
    "Healthcare.MentalHealth",
    "Healthcare.Obesity",
    "Healthcare.Osteoporosis",
    "Healthcare.PAD",
    "Healthcare.PalliativeCare",
    "Healthcare.RheumatoidArthritis",
    "Healthcare.Smoking",
    "Healthcare.Stroke",
    # Legal Applications
    "Legals",
    "Legals.Cookies",
    "Legals.Privacy",
    # Media Applications
    "Media",
    "Media.Books",
    "Media.Radio",
    "Media.RSS",
    "Media.TV",
    # Social Services Applications
    "SocialServices",
    # User Applications
    "Users",
    "Users.Accountants",
    "Users.Accounts",
    "Users.Dentists",
    "Users.Doctors",
    "Users.Headteachers",
    "Users.Lawyers",
    "Users.Parents",
    "Users.Politicians",
    "Users.Staff",
    "Users.Students",
    "Users.Teachers",
    # Add your apps here to enable them
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    # the social providers
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.agave",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.amazon",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.angellist",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.asana",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.auth0",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.authentiq",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.baidu",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.basecamp",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.bitbucket",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.bitbucket_oauth2",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.bitly",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.cern",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.coinbase",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.dataporten",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.daum",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.digitalocean",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.discord",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.disqus",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.douban",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.draugiem",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.dropbox",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.dwolla",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.edmodo",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.edx",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.eveonline",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.evernote",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.exist",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.feedly",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.fivehundredpx",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.flickr",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.foursquare",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.fxa",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.github",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.gitlab",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.google",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.hubic",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.instagram",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.jupyterhub",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.kakao",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.keycloak",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.line",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin_oauth2",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.mailru",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.mailchimp",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.meetup",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.microsoft",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.mixer",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.naver",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.nextcloud",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.odnoklassniki",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.openid",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.openstreetmap",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.orcid",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.paypal",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.patreon",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.persona",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.pinterest",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.reddit",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.robinhood",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.sharefile",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.shopify",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.slack",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.soundcloud",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.spotify",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.stackexchange",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.steam",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.strava",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.stripe",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.trello",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.tumblr",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.twentythreeandme",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitch",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.untappd",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.vimeo",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.vimeo_oauth2",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.vk",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.weibo",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.weixin",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.windowslive",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.xing",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.yandex",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.ynab",

),

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        # For each OAuth based provider, either add a ``SocialApp``
        # (``socialaccount`` app) containing the required client
        # credentials, or list them here:
        'APP': {
            'client_id': '123',
            'secret': '456',
            'key': ''
        }
    }
}

PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
)

# Middleware framework
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    ##'Website.middleware.current_user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Website.urls'

# Template configuration
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Website.wsgi.application'
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES={
   'default':{
       'ENGINE':'sql_server.pyodbc',
       'NAME':'NKFSLTD_Website',
       'USER':'Nf00038',
       'PASSWORD':'hidden',
       'HOST':'192.168.1.116',
       'PORT':'1433',      
       'OPTIONS':{
           'driver':'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
       },
   }
}
    
    # Some other example server values are
    # server = 'localhost\sqlexpress' # for a named instance
    # server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port

class SQLConnection():

    def Connection():

        server = '192.168.1.118' 
        database = 'NKFSLTD_Website' 
        username = 'sa' 
        password = 'Heron24$' 
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()




# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = ('G:\inetpub\FaulknerandSonsLTD2\Website\Website\Website\static\static_root') 
STATICFILES_DIRS = (('G:\inetpub\FaulknerandSonsLTD2\Website\Website\Website\static\staticfiles'),)

STUDENTS_URL = '/studentsfiles/'
STUDENTS_ROOT = ('I:\Students')
STUDENTFILES_DIRS = ('I:\Students')

PARENTS_URL = '/parentsfiles/'
PARENTS_ROOT = ('H:\Parents')
PARENTFILES_DIRS = ('H:\Parents')

TEACHERS_URL = '/teachersfiles/'
TEACHERS_ROOT = ('C:\Teachers')
TEACHERSFILES_DIRS = ('C:\Teachers')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
#MEDIA_ROOT = ('G:\inetpub\FaulknerandSonsLTD2\Website\Website\Website\media\media_root') 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'firstapp/static/')

# django registration
ACCCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
```

Comment: Can you showe the `INSTALLED_APPS` of your `settings.py` Looks like there is a problem with that?

Comment: Please see the edit above :)

Comment: As I answered earlier you've tuple of tuple of strings because of extra comma `INSTALLED_APPS = (...),` which is interpreted as `INSTALLED_APPS = tuple(tuple(...))`, you should avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

You created a tuple in a tuple here

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "app",
    "Website",
    #some more apps
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.ynab",
),
```

Removing the string we get `INSTALLED_APPS = (),` which is the same as `INSTALLED_APPS = ((), ())`.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) you should have a list such as

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "app",
    "Website",
    #some more apps
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.ynab",
]
```

Note that there is **no comma** in the last line.

Removing the strings we now get `INSTALLED_APPS = []`.

Answer (score 0):

INSTALLED_APPS should looks like tuple of strings:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = ("app1", "app2")
```

but you have list somewhere in it, ie:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = ("app1", ["app2"])
```

Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps

Answer (score 0):

IN:

```
File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py",
> line 24, in setup
```

you can find:

> ```
>     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
> ```

and in

```
>       File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
> line 91, in populate
```

you can find:

```
>         app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
```

and in:

```
>       File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py",
> line 90, in create
```

you can find:

```
>         module = import_module(entry)
```

and in:

```
>       File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Shared\Python37_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 118,
> in import_module
```

you can find:

```
>         if name.startswith('.'):
```

but the settings.INSTALLED_APPS looks good, are you sure that you still have this error

I was able to reproduce the problem when I added a ',' just after the definition of INSTALLED_APPS

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

please change

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (),
```

to

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ()
```

Comment: I have checked all of your suggestions and can confirm no code is missing.

Comment: if python installation works fine with other scripts, the pb comes then from Django settings. but what you've shared seems good

Comment: Its that i'm not able to start the server running

Comment: Please share all your settings

Comment: I have a copy of the model available to download, however as I have used a URL shortener it is not letting me share directly on here. Any suggestions?

Comment: please share your settings.py file

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add my solution as i also stumbled into this problem. it had nothing to do with any error in the code, but was something to do with python system setup. was able to reproduce that one branch had the error and another didnt, despite no code changes. fixed by changing back over to the system python. previously i had moved to a lower python because of similar errors when upgrading python. but seems to have been fixed when i got brew and pyenv to see eachother. so that they werent linked before may have been the root of my problem at least, leading to py and depenedncy mismatch? and ultimately leading to this endswith error despite no code bug.